# load external site into div

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe

How can I load an external site onto another site? (load the entire page without scroll, borders)

I tried this but it does not load the entire page, and there are scroll/borders?)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.externaldomain.com"  name="iframeName" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: seamless, what does this do? http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Google does not allow iframing

Comment: Add what you have already tried, what you are trying to accomplish, and what you have found out so far.

Comment: Just testing :) (I dont actually want to load google.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the borders using CSS and then expanding the iFrame to encompass your entire client site using JavaScript. In this way, no one will notice a thing.

But sometimes the host site is clever enough to avoid that by checking the `window.top` against `window.self` element.

Comment: that is fine, I own both sites :) got an example?

Comment: Assuming you get the width and height of the window by the method outlined [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow), and store them in the variable `w` and `h` respectively, and you have the iframe as `var iframe`, you can do `iframe.style.width=w+"px";`, `iframe.style.height=h+"px";`,`iframe.style.position="absolute";`,`iframe.style.left="0px";`, and `iframe.style.top="0px";`. This will position the iframe in a way that it should encompass the whole of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Milad said, you can set the IFRAME dimensions to fill the browser window.

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="mypage.php" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling></iframe>
```

An example using jQuery:

```
$('#my-iframe').css('height', $(window).height());
```

Don't forget to reset the page's margins and paddings with CSS to avoid unwanted spaces:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Becareful if you have more elements on the same page, like a heading bar. If so, subtract the window height by the others elements heights.